# Regarding QUEUE in sql server and its real usage

Tags: sql-server, queue

apologized for posting many question in one thread.

i have many doubts for queue in sql server. i searched google for queque for beginner like article but got nothing still. so i like to post few question regarding queue.

1) what is queue in sql server and what for people use queue ?

2) i guess people would store data in queue but why because we can store data in table then why people would use queue ?

3) how to create a queue

```
CREATE QUEUE ExpenseQueue
    WITH STATUS=ON,
    ACTIVATION (
        PROCEDURE_NAME = expense_procedure,
        MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 5,
        EXECUTE AS 'ExpenseUser' ) ;
```

the above statement and their option is not clear to me.

4) how to store data in queue ?

5) can queue has many field like table ?

6) can we store a customer details in queue like (custid, Name, phoneno etc) ?

7) when queue data is removed or dequeue ?

8) suppose 10 data is stored in queue then how could i read a data from queue whose custid=5 ?

9) can we explicitly remove one or two data from queue ?

10) discuss the best situation when people would use queue to store/read data from queue instead of table?

11) what is the difference between queue and table ?

please answer point wise in details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Mostly for asynchronouse processing. That is, something that you know is going to take a long time and you don't need your end-user to wait for
2. It's a temporary storage solution, with the intention to process the messages in the queue at a later date.
3. You're going to have to read [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190495.aspx).
4. [The send statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188407.aspx).
5. No. This should be evident from the syntax of `create queue`; you're not specifying any columns or datatypes.
6. You can store pretty much anything you want. A message on the queue has a payload (typically the details of the thing that you need to process later).
7. When you call the [receive statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186963.aspx)
8. A queue isn't designed for this method of data access
9. Yes. Call receive as many times as you want (or with a `top` clause)
10. As I said before, you don't store data in a queue long term. A contrived use case would be in an HR scenario when an employee leaves. From the front end, HR just says "terminate employee". On the back end, it puts a message on a queue and something later comes through and processes all of the places where that employee needs to be cleaned up from (payroll, active directory, etc). But the user doesn't need to wait for all of that.
11. Too many to enumerate.

In short, I don't know if you've suddenly found yourself in a position to have to support an environment that is using Service Broker or if you've found a solution in need of a problem. Regardless, I'd do some reading up on the architecture [in books online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166104%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: i just like to know can't we work with queue without service broker?

Comment: No. A queue is a service broker structure.